# Should I use "and" to connect these two clauses?

Tags: conjunctions

> Music has long been a subtle means of expressing emotions as well as thoughts of its composers and singers, **and** some people believe its purpose is to bring people closer, regardless of their cultures and age groups.

"And" is the best word I can think of, but it would be of great help if anyone can suggest an alternative conjunction.

Comment: You could drop the conjunction and use a semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

You could end the first sentence with a period. And start the second with "Furthermore/In addition".

The first sentence is taking about "music" being a means of expressing emotions. The second sentence is talking about the intended purpose of music (as some believe it).

Or you could drop the "and", like Mr. J.R suggested, and use the semicolon.

Even starting the second sentence with "Some people ..." keeps the meaning intact, to me the conjunction does not add anything. Using the conjunction does not seem to improve the sentence.